# Get class name by Consumer<> object

Tags: reflection, java-8, method-reference

I want to detect class name using object of `Consumer<>` class.

Example

```
MyClass myObject = new MyClass();

someMethod(myObject::myMethod);

void someMethod(Consumer<String> fn) {
    // here i want to know class name "MyClass" through fn
}
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Possible [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)? In other words, are you trying to solve some underlying problem, or are you just curious about this? If the former, please tell us more about the underlying problem.

Comment: Thanks, i knew nothing about term 'XY Problem'. But my problem is no 'XY Problem'. My solution in next comment.

Comment: I needed class name just for logging.

Answer (score 0):

The `fn` parameter doesn't hold information about the calling class.

However, you can implement a utility class with a single `static` method, that does the job for you. You can take advantage of the array that the `Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()` expression results to in order to inspect the trace of callbacks that lead to your method. For example:

```
public final class CallInspector {
    public final static String getCallingClassName() {
        StackTraceElement[] stElements = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
        return IntStream.range(1, stElements.length)
                        .mapToObj(i -> stElements[i].getClassName())
                        .filter(name -> !name.equals(CallInspector.class.getName()))
                        .findFirst()
                        .orElse(null);
    }
}
```

Note that we're skipping the `StackTraceElement` at index `0`, as it will always be `java.lang.Thread`.

Then, in your `myMethod()` just invoke the utility one:

```
void someMethod(Consumer<String> fn) {
     String callerClass = CallInspector.getCallingClassName();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, interesting approach. But I wrote easier, already.
My solution looks like 
`someMethod(myObject::myMethod, myObject.getClass().getSimpleName());
void someMethod(Consumer<String> fn, String caller){}`